# Is is feasible to build an audio recorder with SD card storage using ATmega 16 or 32?

Tags: avr, audio, atmega, atmel

Is is feasible to build an audio recorder with SD card storage using ATmega 16 or 32 running at say 16 MHz?

If yes, what would it need in components? I don't expect you to make a device for me, but a high level overview of needed parts would be welcome.

I'm thinking of using an electret microphone and use the integrated ADC to capture audio and then save the signal to a FAT formatted SD card in a popular sound format if possible but if needed I could make a custom format and convert the data once it reaches PC.

I know that I'd of course need a power supply, SD card reader, microphone, AVR itself, but would I need some sort of filter at microphone's input? I'm mostly targeting human speech and it appears that I need to mainly focus at frequencies from 60 Hz to 7 kHz. I also heard that most of useful data is below 3 kHz.

Also right now, I don't have the feel for amount of memory the device would need, so if ATmega 32 is overkill, which smaller AVR would fit? I hope to go for as low pin count as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's feasible.

[Here's a good tutorial for an MSP430 version](http://www.diylife.com/2008/05/16/record-audio-with-the-msp430-microcontroller/) (by Ian Lesnet of Bus Pirate fame).

Comment: Looks nice! I also found the [AVR335](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc1456.pdf) application note which describes use of ADC and storing data on flash memory.

Answer (score 2):

definitely doable ( i just finished one with 8Khz sampling )

SD tricks are explained here : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/why-is-the-sd-library-slow/49791

check timers from PCMAudio and http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM

also http://letsmakerobots.com/node/28278 for the timers explanations

Comment: Nice answer! Also thanks for reminding me about this project. I spent quite a while working on this, but never actually got to the point of making it.